# Android convert double to duration

Tags: java, android, excel-formula, kotlin, duration

I am trying to convert an excel formula into Kotlin code. But I am facing issue in converting a double into duration. The Excel displays in duration format. How do I convert to Duration format? I cant use Duration as API level is less than 26.

```
The result in 
Excel Duration format - 0:47:22
Excel Number format - 0.03288861121
```

I am able to get it in the number format. But unable to convert it into time duration.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you want as the output. Do you want the string `"0:47:22"`? The number is the number of days, so you can multiply that by `24*60*60` to get the number of seconds, and then format that as a string anyway you want.

Comment: This does not seem to be an issue with excel... Why tag it as such?

Comment: You *can*  use `Duration` from java.time (the modern Java date and time API) at your API level. Add ThreeTenABP to your Android project, see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). Then make sure to import from `org.threeten.bp`, for example `org.threeten.bp.Duration`.

Answer (score 4):

I am unsure whether the following is the best solution. You may be able to get something better from Excel somehow. In any case it works.

```
    double durationDoble = 0.03288861121;
    Duration dur = Duration.ofNanos((long) (durationDoble * TimeUnit.DAYS.toNanos(1)));
    System.out.println(dur);
```

This prints

> PT47M21.576008544S

If you are not used to the `Duration` class and/or ISO 8601 format, it may look a bit funny, but it means 47 minutes 21.576 seconds, so if rounded to whole seconds it agrees with what you expected.

> I cant use Duration as API level is less than 26.

Yes, you can use `Duration` from java.time (the modern Java date and time API) in API levels less than 26. Add ThreeTenABP to your Android project and make sure to import `org.threeten.bp.Duration`.

**Links**

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (ThreeTen for JSR-310, where java.time was first described)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).